# get localstorage item in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a file `index.html` with one iframe set and iframe source points to another domain. I am setting localstorage in `index.html` and trying to get the value in iframe source.(`sample.html`)

```
File 1
index.html
    <html>
    <head>
    //js file 
    </head>
    <body>
    setting localstorage
    Iframe src="55.10.45.045/sample.html"
    </body>
    </html>

file 2
sample.html
       <html>
        <head>
        //js file 
        </head>
        <body>
        getting localstorage Item //Returns null
        </body>
        </html
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Are we talking about setting up localstorage in one domain and getting that in another domain that's not possbile as far as I know.

Comment: The set and get is done by the browser, locally. No matter about the location or if in or out an iframe. But the thing is that code above is NOT valid HTML anyway. So...

Comment: @hakuna matata: I kindly suggest you to read more on [iframe tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and on [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). **Then**, come back with a [minimal, complete and verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

You want to use something like this.

Sending information:

```
  window.onload = function() {
      var win = document.getElementById('iFrameId').contentWindow;

      win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({

          key: 'dataKey',
          data: dataPassing

      }), "*");

  };
```

Receiving information:

```
window.onmessage = function(e) {

     var payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
     localStorage.setItem(payload.key, payload.data);

};
```

This will pass a JSON object into the iFrame, then the script in the frame will take it and push it into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this...

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<a href="sample.html">click</a>
<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("link", "http://www.w3schools.com/");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("link");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<iframe src='"+localStorage.getItem("link")+"' width='100%' height='350px' />";
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```